Finding contiguous words in a list which match the string
In our application, we are reading the text from PDF and processing it.
I'm stuck with a scenario which is as below:
Suppose, I have below lines in a PDF page:
It's raining in the evening
John is sitting on a desk    *
and working on his laptop    *
Andy enters the building

Note - * can be present at beginning or end of a line or both.
After reading lines from PDf, I'm removing the * characters and converting the lines to sentences. So, I get the the below sentences:
It's raining in the evening
John is sitting on a desk and working on his laptop
Andy enters the building

This PDF is also processed using some technology which provide the words in the PDF. So, I get a list of words for the lines as:
It's 
raining 
in 
the 
evening
John 
is 
sitting 
on 
a 
desk 
*
and 
working 
on 
his 
laptop
*
Andy 
enters 
the 
building

I need to find the contiguous words in the list which are matching a particular sentence.
I have written a logic which works fine if there are no * characters in the PDF.
But it fails if * is present.
Any idea what is the best way to perform the matching in this case?
Thanks in advance!

How do you know what is the start of a sentence?

In the input list, how are you differentiating between evening and john to be part of different sentence?
